# JS benefits of using reduce over for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there are any **benefits** for using reduce over the for loop. (except for it's shorter)

Let's take, for example, the sum function.

```
function sum(arr) {
   return arr.reduce((acc, current) => acc + current, 0);
}
```

Or with for.

```
function sum(arr) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    total += arr[i];
  }
  return total;
}
```

Comment: `for-loop` it's always faster in comparison to anything, period! :-).. The benefit of `reduce`: readability.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from brevity, as you mentioned, it also helps in readability: `reduce` is explicit in what it does whereas a for loop is generic.

Performance wise `reduce` is generally slower, especially if using an anonymous function.

Comment: Especially if using an anonymous function? Can you explain?